# Not able read part files from parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

> HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Can not read value at 0 in block 0 in file s3://xx/xxxx/part-xxxxxxxxxx.parquet.

I have created the parquet files using AWS glue dynamic frame write api, when I'm trying to read through AWS athena from glue catalog table, getting this error.

When I'm trying to read this file through glue catalog via dynamic frame, this seems to be fine, but Athena is giving be the above mentioned error.

Worked with the avro format, there seems to be no issue in that.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_name`(
`column_name_1` string, 
`column_name_2` string
 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
 OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
 LOCATION
  's3://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='xxxxxxxxxx', 
  'averageRecordSize'='xxxxx', 
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='xxxxx', 
  'recordCount'='xxx', 
  'sizeKey'='xxxx', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Comment: What is the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name and this table created via crawler or DDL ?

Comment: @bdcloud, it is giving me entire schema and table is created via crawler

Comment: Can you post the output here or update your question with it?

Comment: can you try running the DDL with out table properties and also check the parquet file schema if they are valid  https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issue with smallint in case of athena,it is having not null value

It cannot not used with smallint and any other data type, for that reason we get above mentioned error.

A solution would be converting smallint to string before to s3 in parquet